# What is the object in this photo?

Tags: amateur-observing, observational-astronomy, photography

What object is in this photo?

View coordinates: $47.25103 \ \ 38.81697$

Time: $2013$-$11$-$23 ~21$:$00 +4 ~UTC$

Sony $A580, \ 50mm f/1.4 15"$

[image: M31 Andromeda Galaxy]

Comment: It's no night clubs with lasers or strong LED lights. Can this be M31?

Comment: Camera lay lens up and looked on the zenith.

Comment: http://nightskyinfocus.com/2013/04/08/andromeda-galaxy-wide-field-november-11-2012/

Comment: http://nova.astrometry.net/user_images/942615 is a fairly helpful tool as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your guess was correct. It is the [Andromeda Galaxy, M31](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andromeda_Galaxy).

Here is a map of the part of the sky near zenith at the place and time you provided: [Sky map for Taganrog, Russia on 11/23/2013 5:00:00 PM UTC](http://www.skymaponline.net/view.aspx?r=4556&x=4454&y=4666&lat=47.2492935&long=38.8201646&time=20131123170000&rotation=90&w=1300&h=800&gmtoffset=60&loc=Taganrog,%20Russia&id=7e9537b31b). Even the rotation is small. The sky map is rotated approximately 30° counter clockwise relative to the photo. You were approximately facing south when taking it.
[image]

On your picture there is a part of the [Andromeda constellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andromeda_%28constellation%29). I will use only a small bottom part of your picture (below the imaginary horizontal line going through M31) to identify the constellation.

- The bright star to the left of M31, very close to the edge is [μ Andromedae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_Andromedae) (marked `37 μ And` on the sky map). It is the star between [Mirach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_Andromedae) (out of photo) and M31.
- On the bottom of the right part of the photograph you see three stars on a imaginary vertical line: [ψ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psi_Andromedae), [κ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kappa_Andromedae) and [ι](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iota_Andromedae) Andromedae.
- Between ψ and κ, to the right there is [λ Andromedae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_Andromedae) (marked `16 λ And` and connected with μ on the sky map).

The bottom of the three stars in the upper-left corner of your photo is [φ Andromedae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi_Andromedae) (connected by the vertical line with `37 μ And` on the sky map).

The `1 ο And` on the sky map is not on your photo.